# mdfind equivalent on linux?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, find

Mac OS X is a beautiful system, from the mach kernel up to finder and spotlight and speaking of spotlight, it truly blew me away when I just needed to execute this command to get all unix executables and ONLY unix executales:

```
mdfind "kMDItemKind == 'Unix Executable'"
```

Amazing!!! Really!!!

Now, the question is does anyone know of an equivalent unix or linux command that doesn't involve complex find incantations or doesn't return false positives (like someone perming all their images rwxrwxrwx ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Beagle](http://www.beagle-project.org/), [MetaTracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/), [Strigi](http://strigi.sourceforge.net/), and even [Google Desktop](http://desktop.google.com/) are all desktop indexers for Linux.  What's there by default depends on your distribution (some may have none at all), and they all have different tools and interfaces, but the first three support [Xesam](http://xesam.org/), so [xesam-tool](http://xesam.org/people/kamstrup/xesam-tools/xesam-tools-0.6.1.tar.gz) can provide a `mdfind`-like command-line interface.

Answer (score 8):

There are 3 ways to go about this under Linux.

#### 1. use a location tool

You can use the commands `locate`, `which`, and `whereis` to find programs and files matching a pattern on your system.

#### 2. executables are kept in designated areas

90% of the executables on a Linux system are either installed under `/usr/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/bin`, or `/sbin` so it isn't really a mystery what executables are available.

#### 3. use find

Use find to locate files that have their executable bits set (--x--x--x).

```
% find . -executable -type f
```

#### 4. use your package manager

You could also use your Linux distros' package manager (yum, apt, etc.) to find out what executables are installed for either a given package or all the packages installed.

Comment: That is really not the same thing, although the `find` command can solve what the asker needs. Spotlight is blazingly fast, and supports full text search of basically your entire hard drive. Once you get used to this, there is really no turning back!

Comment: Not an answer to the question; none of these tools does file *content* indexing.

Answer (score 4):

Not really, none of the other UNIX system have an indexer builtin the file system (except BeOS but it is not a UNIX system and mostly dead anyway).  You can have something not too far with the `locate(1)` command on all BSD systems (the daily script create the locate database with `locate.updatedb`) but this is only enables you to find pathnames.  It does not deal with metadata such as keywords and file types.

To be honest, this is one of the best things amongs others about MacOS X, just live with it :)

Comment: Or most terrible things since Yosemite and also now in El Capitan. The search is broken in .tex files. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/206328/15504

Comment: It only just occurred to me that `mdfind` is the closest thing to the amazing but defunct Google Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

[rga (ripgrep-all)](https://github.com/phiresky/ripgrep-all) allows to search over dozens of data formats (text, audio, and video) and builds a cache/index. Runs on Linux and it is in most distributions package managers (apt, pacman, etc).

Comment: Oh wow, I'd dismissed ripgrep as an unnecessary substitute for grep yet had previously been looking for a grep with indexing. Thanks for bringing this back to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ls -Rla / | grep regexOrNameOfSomethingYouAreLookingFor &
```

Best to put this in the BG as it can take a while. Also focussing it to a specific location or the WD speeds it up tremendously:

```
sudo ls -Rla ~/Documents/ | grep regexOrNameOfSomethingYouAreLookingFor
```

Comment: Sorry, but NO, a big NO. First: what you do is searching on file *names*, not file *content* (and you do so by using [gulp] `ls` of all things!). Second, for what you do, indexing file locations, there's a tool fhat this tons more elegantly and efficiently: `mlocate(1)`.